# Compound primary key edit view MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm trying to edit a Students grade in a linker table that contains the Student Id and the Course Id. I've looked around a bit, and have seen that I need to take in two id parameters into the view rather than just the one id, and then change the action link to take two parameters. But when i click on the edit button in the index, I get a 404 saying the page can't be found. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Here's my index view

```
@model IEnumerable<S00132671CA2.Models.StudentCourse>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Grade)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Grade)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id= item.StudentId, CourseId = item.CourseId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.StudentId, Course = item.CourseId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Here's my Edit action

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int? StudentId, int? CourseId)
        {
            StudentCourse courseList = db.StudentCourse.Find(StudentId, CourseId);
            if (courseList == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.StudentId = new SelectList(db.Students, "StudentId", "StudentName", courseList.StudentId);
            ViewBag.CourseId = new SelectList(db.Courses, "CourseId", "CourseName", courseList.CourseId);
            return View(courseList);
        }
```

Here's my model if it's any help

```
public class StudentCourse
    {
         [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
         public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
          [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
          public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
          public double Grade { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { StudentId = item.StudentId, CourseId = item.CourseId })
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you for taking the time out of your day to answer!